# TypeError: $(...).accordion is causing all other functions to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, typeerror

I am having trouble with UI Accordion. It keeps on showing this error: `TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function` which also causing all of my other Javascript function to stop working.

Here is a live test: http://loai.directory/test/modules

I changed the according function from:

```
//Accordion
$(".accordion").accordion({ header: ".accordionHead", collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content" });
```

to

```
//Accordion
$(function() {
    $(".accordion").accordion({ header: ".accordionHead", collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content" });
});
```

But it still didn't work.

Comment: have you loaded jqueryui library

Comment: Indeed, as you can see in the test site: I am calling: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: jquery.min.js doesn't contain jQuery UI. It's a separate library.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle, so we can debug

Comment: @Juhana where shall I call the functions from? i tried by adding them before body closing tag in a <script> but same problem

Comment: Either you didn't understand my comment, or I didn't understand yours, but what I'm trying to say is that you need to download and include the jQuery UI library separately. If all you have is jquery.min.js then you have only the base jQuery library that doesn't have an `.accordion()` method.

Comment: @Juhana it worked, I added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>` and `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

So I had to have these three for it to work?

Comment: No, you're including jQuery UI twice. Either use a local copy or one from the CDN but not both.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I am sorry for not explaining my question 'properly' - I just didn't know how to explain the problem, I only know HTML and CSS well, but quite a beginner with JS. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code is setting the `<base href>` to some `http://localhost/` URL. You need to remove that line.

Then it should be able to access all of the resources.